# Center brand in navbar with items on each side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am trying to center my brand containing a logo in my navbar. I essentially want a centered brand with menu items surrounding it (eg. two menu items to the left and two to the right of the brand).

I have tried several things such as this: [Wrap Bootstrap navbar list items around centered brand image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473939/wrap-bootstrap-navbar-list-items-around-centered-brand-image), and it works, but I would very much prefer a solution without javascript.

I have also tried something like this

```
.navbar-header {
float: left;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {float:none;}
```

but this only centers the brand, and does not move it in between the menu items, therefore stacking on top of them.

I have also tried just adding the logo to a menu item, and while this works on desktops, it does not look very good on mobile devices since it is an ordinary menu item and is therefore a part of the drop down menu.

Here's a couple of examples of what I have tried: http://www.bootply.com/114800 and http://www.bootply.com/114804.

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do yo have any code to share? What is the problem you're running into?

Comment: I should have explained myself better, edited my question.

Comment: What about the second bootply link is different from what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Try looking at it with the mobile device view. The brand is a part of the drop down menu, not the navbar header. I would like the brand to be centered in the navbar header when on mobile devices too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! This is quite similar to what I did first, but I added CSS that will make it work on mobile devices too.

Firstly, I simply added a menu item between my other menu items

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

like so. I also kept the normal brand that is default in the bootstrap navbar, but added the visible-xs class to make it visible on lower resolutions only

```
<a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
```

Then I have the following CSS to support it. All it does is simply hide the logo from the navigation and display the default branding instead

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav .logo {
        display:none;
    }
}

.navbar-nav .logo {
    opacity: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of some css I use for 3 sections (to center one section in the middle). If you are going to try to achieve this by floating you need to float all the elements so that they are relative to each other. I place these inside a div with class .blocky.

(EDIT): I added some information to make sure this is centered for you. And technically you could do away with the right section class, and just place the left and then middle sections afterward, but at one point I was using the right class to clear something. So play with it as you will.

```
<div class="blocky">
     <div class="leftSection">
     </div>
     <div class="middleSection">
     </div>
     <div class="rightSection">
     </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need further explanation or if I can make this clearer. BTW, the clears in the css are to make sure that nothing else ends up placed in this alignment, and of course the padding, margins, and width numbers can all be changed or in some cases done away with entirely.

```
.blocky
{
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float:none;
}
.leftSection
{
  float: left;
  width: 236px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  clear: left;
 }

.rightSection
{
  float: right;
  width: 236px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  clear:right;
}

.middleSection
{
  float: left;
  width: 236px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! While this solution does work, it is no different from just adding a menu item in between the others it seems. I still have the problem of the brand not being displayed properly on mobile devices.

Comment: Hmm, left my phone at home so I'm at a loss as to how to address that. I will say that i use the above css on a site that displays exactly as it does for desktop on mobile devices. I just use left then middle middle middle, no right section. I will take a look at this at lunch if possible. Keep in mind I added some info to center that .blocky section, so make sure you've incorporated that.