# How could I center the logo in the navigation bar, with an uneven amount of menu items on each side?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am coding a design I found for practice and am trying to get the logo in the center of the navbar like in the dribble link.

https://dribbble.com/shots/4424634-MIFESTIVAL-Home-Page/attachments/1005722

There are 4 items on the left, and only two on the right. I originally had them all floated left and couldnt figure it out, so I tried flexbox, because I found this tip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21862333/7723283

This only works if I have an even amount of items in the navigation. I am also wondering if I am okay including all those items as normal navigation instead of buttons or something. This css is basically the same as the link above, so my nav items are all positioned equally. But I need the logo in the center. I feel like there is something easily to be done with flexbox, but this is the first time I have used it.

```css
nav{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
  background:#eee;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

#logo{
  width: 200px;
  height:100%;
  background:rgb(126, 232, 163);
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <a href="#">Menu icon</a></li>
   <a href="#">Search icon</a></li>
   <a href="plan.html">Plan Your Trip</a></li>
   <a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
   <a href="index.html" id="logo">mifestival</a></li>
   <a href="tickets.html">Tickets</a></li>
   <a href="line-up.html">Line-Up</a></li>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're missing quite a few <li>'s there

Comment: Does that actually matter? I had that at first, and it kinda complicated my css a bit, and I had seen it be done with just the anchor tags, so I did it this way.

Comment: No...unfortunately, flexbox won't help you here...without a **lot** of restucturing.

Comment: no need of lis here ;) just remove the closing tags

Comment: @bjp7809 well it matters if you do keep the closing tag, otherwise your html will not be valid. If you don't want li's, remove the closing tag. Is there a reason you do not simply divide your nav into 3 sections, left, middle and right and position those?

Comment: @G-Cyr Oh haha! I didn't even notice that. oops

Comment: if you wrap your element within 3 containers, then it turns to be easy : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gzJEJw  ;)  (did not make this an answer since a similar structure is used in the answer below .. but take a look at the css using the flex propertie to squeeze at center your logo  ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple restructure to get you started:

We'll wrap up the chunks of your menu into three distinct parts (left side, middle/logo, right side)

```
<nav>
    <div class="leftSide">
        <a href="#">Menu icon</a>
        <a href="#">Search icon</a>
        <a href="plan.html">Plan Your Trip</a>
        <a href="experience.html">Experience</a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html" id="logo">mifestival</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSide">
        <a href="tickets.html">Tickets</a>
        <a href="line-up.html">Line-Up</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And for the CSS we'll add in this:

```
.leftSide {
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.rightSide {
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks! So did you do the 100px in the calc because I want the width of the logo to be 200px? And Does making an item inside of a container that is display:flex, also display:flex, does that just make it a flex item?

Comment: Yep the calc for 100px, was spacing for the logo. As for display flex, not really, nesting flex containers is an easy way to get complex layouts. In this case it's one big flex container with 3 flex items (all the divs I added) and each of those is a flex container with some links or a logo