# How do I center a Bootstrap nav bar with a brand image inbetween nav links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

So I've designed a mock website layout for a made up company so I can test my skills at Twitter's Bootstrap 3 but I'm having problems relaying what I've designed on photoshop to code.

I'm trying to get the whole navbar content centered, with links at either side of the brand logo. I've checked online, google, stackoverflow and more, however I can't seem to get it anywhere near what I've designed! I'm having a hard time getting my head around it. It seems like it should be simple, and I've just overthought it's complexity! The links need to be center to the image, but also center in the navbar itself. The layout as such:

[link]  [link]  [LOGO]  [link]  [link]

Here's an image of the mentioned design:

[image]

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23400234/2976720), where these two answers could solve your problem: [answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23400451/2976720), [answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23412513/2976720)

Comment: @Bastiaan Thanks! I've already looks at those both, however the links seem to be set to the far left and right of the brand rather than centred with the brand logo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473939/wrap-bootstrap-navbar-list-items-around-centered-brand-image

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I center a brand image with other elements in Bootstrap 3.2's navbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924170/how-can-i-center-a-brand-image-with-other-elements-in-bootstrap-3-2s-navbar)

Comment: Hey @vanburenx, thanks for that link! From that question there was [this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/oJI0QzytvR). I've managed to get this so far [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jmmJpFJw33#) but the li text links don't seem to be centered vertically? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @RossWSimpson - Is this what you are looking for [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p9q16fek/) ?

Comment: @DavidDomain Hey David! That is exactly that! Yes! Is there a way to get that centered when the text is all different lengths? The logo seems off center when you enter the link titles. Also can you explain what you did? Thank you so much!

Comment: @RossWSimpson -  have posted an answer with centered logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the floated `navbar-nav` you can use relative position and negative `left`, `right` values on the `navbar-nav` itself and on the list items or child elements.

To make sure that the logo is always centered you may think about not using a `nav-justified` but a regular `navbar-nav` with a fixed value for left and right `padding` on the anchor tags, but with individual values for different screens.

To get the vertical alignment working just add the appropriate `line-height` to the anchor tags.

I have decided to hide the actual `navbar-brand` and only show it on sx breakpoint.
  For the centered logo it is the other way around, so we do not have the logo inside the collapsed nav. Just look at the example and i am sure you will get the idea.

Here is the example.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.navbar {
  background-color: #231f20;
  min-height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 96px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    position: relative;
    right: -50%;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    line-height: 126px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 24px;
  } 
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    padding: 0 48px;
  } 
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    padding: 0 68px;
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SC9LKtA.png" alt="Brand" width="180" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Food</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SC9LKtA.png" alt="Brand" width="180" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Book a Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Absolute spot on answer, thank you David!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try flexbox display. In order to implement it, you will have to:

1. add the `display: flex` property to the parent element of the elements that you need to align (in this case: on the `<ul>` element in the navbar, which contains the list of navigation links and the brand image)
2. set `margin: auto` for the elements you need to align (in this case: on the `<li>` elements)

Optional: if you don't want your elements to show up in a row (default bahavior), adjust the value of the `flex-direction` property. E.g. if you want to have the elements listed vertically, add `flex-direction: column;` to the `<ul>` element.

Here is a sample code, with two different image-placements: on-top of the list for mobile devices and in the middle of the row for small devices and above.

```
    HTML:
    ...
    <nav class="container">
        <div class="row visible-xs text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="BLUE|BERY"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="text-center">
                    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Food</a></li>
                    <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="BLUE|BERY"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book a Table</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    ...

    CSS:
        body {background-color: #333333;}
        nav {background-color: #000000;}
        nav ul {
            display: flex; 
            list-style-type: none; 
            padding-left: 0;  //in order to eliminate Bootstrap's built-in 40px padding
        }
        nav ul > li {margin: auto;} //N.B. don't alter the margin property, if you want some further adjustments, use padding!
        nav ul > li > a:link, :visited, :hover, :active {
            color: #ffffff; 
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        @media all and (max-width:767px) {
            nav a > img {margin: 20px auto;}
            nav ul {flex-direction: column;} //only if you want to change the default direction
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I couldn't manage to get your code working with mine, however I did manage to do [this](http://www.bootply.com/jmmJpFJw33#) but now the links are not vertically aligned with the image grr. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Yes, flex display is quite sensitive, it doesn't like to be mixed in with others. :)

Comment: Hey, Ross, I created a jsfiddle here: (https://jsfiddle.net/Rpad/syrucoh6/), where you can see the effect of this code. It's responsive, so you have to stretch the result window a bit to see the effect. Is this what you were intended to achieve?